# How to append then query and check a DOM element

Tags: cypress

Working with cypress. Im trying to append a new element to the page and check it rendered ok. (Our code had a bug with this). The test i came up with looks like:

```js
it('should be able to set attributes before append', () => {
  cy.get('body').then(() => {
    const elem: any = document.createElement('ids-tag');
    elem.color = 'red';
    elem.clickable = true;
    elem.dismissible = true;
    elem.id = 'test';
    document.body.appendChild(elem);

    cy.get('#test')
      .invoke('attr', 'color')
      .should('eq', 'red');
  });
});
```

However this is failing because the element is appending in a different body i presume. So a couple questions:

1. is this a good way to test createElement in cypress?
2. how can i get `cy.get('#test')` to work

Did not find much on how to append to the DOM in cypress.

Answer (score 6):

I would start by asking why do you want to test `createElement`? I guess there is something in your app that balks at this operation, but the way it reads is that you are trying to test native browser functions.

I only ask because the answer might give a different test altogether.

On a technical note, your test fails because you have the wrong `document` in the test.

The Cypress test runner is the browser document (the one you reference) and within that page an `<iframe>` contains your actual app.

The app's document is accessed with the `cy.document()` command.

```js
it('should be able to set attributes before append', () => {

  cy.document().then(doc => {
    const elem = doc.createElement('ids-tag');
    elem.color = 'red';
    elem.clickable = true;
    elem.dismissible = true;
    elem.id = 'test';
    doc.body.appendChild(elem);
  })

  cy.get('#test')
    .invoke('attr', 'color')
    .should('eq', 'red');
})
```

Comment: Thanks this looks better. The reason i wanted to test createElement is previously we had errors when creating our custom web components this way (disconnected/connected callback) fired in the wrong ways the settings set before append like color in this example didnt work unless it was in the DOM. Its fixed now but we have a number of ways to create the components that could occur we wanted to test and this is one of them